# C# exporting SQL to Excel Templates

Tags: c#

I'm building a page to extract SQL data into excel template sheets. I'm running into a "The given key was not present in the dictionary" exception. When debugging, it points to the

```
public void AddField(string Column, dynamic Value)
{
    AddField(_KeyList[Column.ToUpper()], Value);
}
```

Part of the "ExcelExport.cs"

Here is my "ExcelExport.cs" code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ScanPortal
{
    public class ExcelExport
    {
        private FileInfo _TemplateFile;
        private int _StartRow;
        private int _CurrentRow;
        private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> _ValueGrid;
        private Dictionary<string, int> _KeyList;
        private Dictionary<int, int> _InsertList;

        public ExcelExport(string Template = "", int StartRowIndex = 1, int KeyRow = 0)
        {
            if (Template != "")
            {
                _TemplateFile = new FileInfo(Template);
            }

            _InsertList = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            if (KeyRow > 0)
            {
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(_TemplateFile))
                {
                    _KeyList = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
                    int ColIndex = 1;
                    int NumBlank = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        object Value = worksheet.Cells[KeyRow, ColIndex].Value;
                        if (Value == null) { NumBlank++; ColIndex++; continue; }
                        NumBlank = 0;
                        _KeyList.Add(Value.ToString().ToUpper(), ColIndex);
                        ColIndex++;
                    } while (NumBlank < 5);
                }
            }

            _StartRow = StartRowIndex;
            _CurrentRow = _StartRow;

            _ValueGrid = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>();
            _ValueGrid.Add(_StartRow, new Dictionary<int, string>());
        }

        public void AddField(int Row, int Column, dynamic Value)
        {
            if (Column < 1 || Row < 1) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            if (Value == null) Value = "";

            if (!_ValueGrid.ContainsKey(_CurrentRow))
            {
                _ValueGrid.Add(Row, new Dictionary<int, string>());
            }

            _ValueGrid[Row].Add(Column, Value.ToString());
        }

        public void AddField(string Column, dynamic Value)
        {
          AddField(_KeyList[Column.ToUpper()], Value);
        }

        public void AddField(int Column, dynamic Value)
        {
            if (Column < 1) throw new System.IndexOutOfRangeException();
            if (Value == null) Value = "";

            _ValueGrid[_CurrentRow].Add(Column, Value.ToString());
        }

        public void NextRow()
        {
            _CurrentRow++;
            _ValueGrid.Add(_CurrentRow, new Dictionary<int, string>());
        }

        public void InsertRow(int count = 1)
        {
            _CurrentRow++;
            _ValueGrid.Add(_CurrentRow, new Dictionary<int, string>());
            _InsertList.Add(_CurrentRow, count);
        }

        public bool GenerateWorkbook(string FileName, bool DownloadSheet = true)
        {
            if (!FileName.ToUpper().Contains(".XLSX"))
            {
                FileName += ".xlsx";
            }
            using (ExcelPackage pck = (_TemplateFile != null ? new ExcelPackage(_TemplateFile, true) : new ExcelPackage()))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

                foreach (var DictRow in _ValueGrid)
                {
                    int RowIndex = DictRow.Key;
                    if (_InsertList.ContainsKey(RowIndex))
                    {
                        ws.InsertRow(RowIndex, _InsertList[RowIndex]);
                    }
                    foreach (var DictColumn in DictRow.Value)
                    {
                        int ColumnIndex = DictColumn.Key;
                        string ColumnValue = DictColumn.Value;

                        ws.Cells[RowIndex, ColumnIndex].LoadFromText(ColumnValue);
                    }
                }

                if (DownloadSheet)
                {
                    HttpResponse Response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
                    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
                    Response.End();
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my "ExportReports.aspx.cs" code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ScanPortal
{
    public partial class ExportReports : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> DropDowns;

 protected void btnVisitation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExcelExport excel = new ExcelExport(Server.MapPath("JSPRC Visit Summary Data Template.xlsx"), 3, 2);

            using (var db = new FormsDataContext())
            {


                excel.AddField("agency", "SCAN");
            }
            excel.GenerateWorkbook("Visit Summary Data");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what line in your code are you getting this particular error..? fyi this error is generally thrown when you are trying to access a key that isn't there..

Comment: line 70 on ExcelExport.cs   How do i get the key there in this case?

Comment: Well, what keys are you using to index your dictionary? I would bet that the key can't be found.

Comment: being that you do not show / display line numbers.. I doubt anyone will take the time to count out the lines ...

Comment: I'm pretty novice. I inherited this incomplete project and trying to get it working. I'm not sure how to find what you're asking for.

Comment: i listed the problem spot at the beginning of the question for that reason @MethodMan

Comment: not a problem sorry for my mis-read

Comment: I am confused in regards to how you are calling `AddField(_KeyList[Column.ToUpper()], Value);` when you get to this line in the debugger is the value `1` or `"1"` if so then you need to change the method signature to take in a Column of Int or Cast the Column as Int.. please confirm my assumptions

Comment: _KeyList shows 1   the Column.ToUpper() shows "agency"   and Value is "SCAN"

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was pointing to the wrong row on the excel template.